# Get trouble running Time Profile in Instruments Xcode 6.1 Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: ios, ipad, instruments, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1

I'm facing a problem with Time Profile and trying to fix this all day but no luck. Hope anyone in there have faced this before and help me resolved this.

I'm developing an iPAd app it communicates with server using socket connection. I debug it successfully by Run button on Xcode but when instrument by Time Profile tool it cannot get the response from the server even have connected with server. I think its strange because my other apps using that tool without any problem.

My environment: Xcode 6.1, Mac OS Yosemite (10.10).

Thanks.